# make file is not running giving error please help me

Tags: c++, makefile

I am running os x maverick, on terminal when run "make" file it give me

```
orcl:wxWidgets arshadkhan$ make

find -name "*.o" -exec rm {} \;

find: illegal option -- n

usage: find [-H | -L | -P] [-EXdsx] [-f path] path ... [expression]

       find [-H | -L | -P] [-EXdsx] -f path [path ...] [expression]

make: *** [clean] Error 1
```

i am in the directory where following files are

```
orcl:wxWidgets arshadkhan$ ls

Makefile    image.jpg   window      window.cpp  window.h
```

I have Xcode version 5.2 and I have installed command line tool as well .

but still i do not know why this Error is .

Arshad

Comment: Look at the rule for "clean" in the makefile. If there is the "find" command, put a '.' between "find" and "-name": "find . -name "

Comment: You may run into more problems like this one. Looks as if the Makefile was built or written for Linux, relying on the GNU versions of certain tools.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to give a path to `find`. Change the line calling `find` in your `Makefile` to look like this:

```
find . -name "*.o" -exec rm {} \;
```

This tells `find` to look in the current directory.

Also you can replace the `-exec rm {} \;` with `-delete`. It does the same think, but is a bit shorter and propably a bit faster.

Comment: now when i run make file it give me error :                                 orcl:wxWidgets arshadkhan$ make
find . -name "*.o" -exec rm {} \;
rm -f window -R
g++ -c window.cpp   `wx-config --cxxflags`  
/bin/sh: wx-config: command not found
window.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'wx/wx.h' file not found
#include <wx/wx.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [window.o] Error 1

Comment: The error tells you that the `wx-config` executable could not be found. Propably you need to install wxWidgets to fix the problem.

Comment: I downloaded wxWidgets to fix the problem but unable to install it I tried many ways like through terminal to create directory but I m stuck and confused how to proceed further to make sure wxWidgets installed .....

Comment: I am trying to run through terminal as mentioned in install.txt of wxWidget of mac directory as